# When is A ⊗ ℚ self-Pontrjagin dual for a compact-Hausdorff topological ring A?

Tags: nt.number-theory, adeles, pontrjagin-duality

The topological ring of finite adeles $\mathbb A \cong \hat{\mathbb Z} \otimes \mathbb Q$ is self-Pontrjagin dual with self-dual Schwartz–Bruhat functional $\mathbb 1_{\hat{\mathbb Z}}$. This fascinating property also applies to $\mathbb Q_p \cong \mathbb Z_p \otimes \mathbb Q$.

It is also the case that a compact Hausdorff topological ring is profinite.

It seems further the case that, for a profinite $A$ which is self-Pontrjagin dual, so is $A[[t]]$.

Let $A$ be a compact Hausdorff topological ring. These insights suggest the question of when $A_{\mathbb Q} \cong A \otimes \mathbb Q$ is self-Pontrjagin dual, and also when we have both $A \subset A \otimes_{\mathbb{Z}} \mathbb Q$ and $\mathbb 1_{A} : A \otimes_{\mathbb{Z}} \mathbb Q \rightarrow \mathbb{C}$ is self-Fourier dual.

It occurs to me that, assuming the theorem for $A$ we can demonstrate it for $A[[t]]$ (which gets a corresponding topology).

Comment: It looks exceeding strange to me to mix plain text, TeX/MathJax, and Unicode characters, in some cases meaning to refer to the same thing but rendering differently in my browser; so I edited to use TeX/MathJax uniformly, as is the norm on this site (except in the title, where some people prefer not to use MathJax).  I hope that this was all right.

Comment: "It is seems further the case": you mean, to be profinite, or to be Pontryagin self-dual? better reformulate.

Comment: @YCor thanks for spotting that, making changes now